# get two values of json into <b-form-select> text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a json with following structure:

```
[
    {"ID": "123", "Name": "Harry", "Age": "22"},
    {"ID": "456", "Name": "Harry", "Age": "18"},
    {"ID": "789", "Name": "Peter", "Age": "20"},
    {"ID": "159", "Name": "Peter", "Age": "19"},
]
```

So at least, just to make clear, every data - based from `Name` and `Age` together - is **unique**, also without the `ID` (!). It's just a example to make it easier to understand.

What I try to do is now to show the `Name` in a `<b-form-select>` with the `Age` in brackets behind. Like this for e.g.: **Peter (20)**.

In the moment I have following code:

```
<b-form-select :options="sortedPersons" text-field="Name" value-field="ID"></b-form-select>
```

I need to pass `value` to my `parent.vue` but want to show text in this one. So I've decided to do this like that.

The only thing I need now is to get following. This example is to show it simply what I want:

`:text-field="'Name' + ' ' + '(' + 'Age' + ')'"`, but this doesn't work.

How can I make it run?

*Additional Info* - I'm running my `json` in `computed` before to sort it.

```
sortedPersons() {
  var array = this.json.map((input) => input);
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to map your data so the text you want is formatted in a single property, or instead drop using the `options` prop and instead manually create the `<option>` tags using a `v-for`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      options: [
          {"ID": "123", "Name": "Harry", "Age": "22"},
          {"ID": "456", "Name": "Harry", "Age": "18"},
          {"ID": "789", "Name": "Peter", "Age": "20"},
          {"ID": "159", "Name": "Peter", "Age": "19"},
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <b-select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.ID" :value="option.ID">
      {{ option.Name }} ({{ option.Age }})
    </option>
  </b-select>

  Selected: {{ selected }}
</div>
```

Comment: Just for additional Info for all: Instead of "only" ```b-select``` i've use ```b-form-select``` and it worked well, too. So thanks for helping me out!

Comment: `<b-select>` is just an alias of `<b-form-select>`, so they're the same component. It's just a habit of mine to use the alias since it's shorter :)